# Node-RED loses connection to server when I add a node

Tags: node.js, node-red

Whenever I drag a new node into my Node-red sheet, it loses connection to the server. Does someone know how to stabilize it?

In Command Prompt, I get the following error:

```
[red] Uncaught Exeption:
TypeError: argument entity must be string, Buffer or fs.Stats
    at etag (C:\Users\Username\Appdata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:55:11)
    at SendStream.setHeader (C:\Users\Username\Appdata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:724:15)
    at SendStream.send (C:\Users\Username\Appdata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:500:8)
    at SendStream.send (C:\Users\Username\Appdata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules\send\node_modules\etag\index.js:500:8)
    at onstat (C:\Users\Username\Appdata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules\send\node_modules\etag\index.js:585:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

I run the vanilla version of node-RED v0.10.10 & Node.js v0.12.4 on Windows 7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [install](http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/installation.html) guide, Node-RED does not currently support node.js 0.12.x

Run it on node.js 0.10.x and things should be better